# Implementing a life counter similar to "Candy Crush" in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to implement a live countdown in libgdx.

I know i need to save dates and such in sharedprefs and I already wrote the getter - setter in an interface. I am trying to wrap my mind around the algorithm but i am unsuccessful so far.

So when the user presses play:

```
Date date = new Date(TimeUtils.millis());

editor.setDate("date", date);
```

Sets the first date, then:

```
Date newDate = new Date(TimeUtils.millis());

newDate = date + 600000; //10 minutes in miliseconds
```

Now in render:

```
if(newDate - TimeUtils.milis()<=0) {        
    life++;
}  else {
    label.setText(""+newDate-TimeUtils.milis());
}
```

Well. Everything seems to be working, but what if a second life is spent or third? Can anyone give me some pointers on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Then `life--;` ?

Comment: If user can play a game when he wants to, then there must be a button to start game. And if there is a button to start game then there must be a `OnClickListener` added on that. So, put `life--;` in that `OnClickListener` then a spell will be casted to the application, and life will be reduced. You can thank me later. ;)

Comment: ok that was obvious :). so you mean that this code is good to go. I hope i dont get bugs all overf the place later on.

Comment: Try this. If any error raises, don't afraid, add that here

Comment: The problem was much more complicated then i assumed. Still struggling but it is not a technicality problem, it is an algorithm issue, I will try to solve it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what do you want, but if you goal is to add life every 10 minutes, I can recommend you next logic. Just count game time in render method.

```
gameTime += dt;
if (gameTime > 600000) {
   life ++;
   gameTime = 0;
}   else
   // smth
}
```

There you dont need to call system `TimeUtils.milis` on each render call